# Displaying the Universal Image Loader ListView in Fragments does not work

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, universal-image-loader

I am trying to make a ListView using the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) inside a fragment using the [SherlockNavigationDrawer](https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer)

**Problem:** The Universal Image Loader works well but only displays a single list item

**InitialFragment.java**

```
public class InitialFragment extends SherlockFragment
{

DisplayImageOptions options;
String[] imageUrls;

protected  AbsListView listView;

public static ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();


public static Fragment newInstance() 
{
    Fragment f = new InitialFragment();
    return f;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View simpleFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu1, container, false);

    imageUrls = com.sherlock.test1.listview.Constants.IMAGES;

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
        .build();


    listView = (ListView) simpleFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.list2);
    ((ListView) listView).setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(getActivity()));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //startImagePagerActivity(position);
        }
    });


    initImageLoader(getActivity());

    return simpleFragmentView;

}

public static void initImageLoader(Context context) 
{
    // This configuration tuning is custom. You can tune every option, you may tune some of them,
    // or you can create default configuration by
    //  ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);
    // method.

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
            .writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
            .build();
    // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
}

public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    Context context;
    ItemAdapter(Context context)
    {
        Log.d("dexter", "in ItemAdapter Constructor");
        this.context = context;
    }
    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

    public class ViewHolder 
    {
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        Log.d("dexter", "in getView");
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list_image, parent, false);
            //view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list_image, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText("Item " + (position + 1));



        InitialFragment.imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], holder.image, options, animateFirstListener);

        return view;
    }
}

public static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener 
{
    static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) 
    {
        if (loadedImage != null) 
        {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
            boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
            if (firstDisplay) 
            {
                FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                displayedImages.add(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**fragment_menu1.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 
</ListView>
```

**If this helps:**

**1.** The InitialFragment is a Child Fragment and is inflated in a FrameLayout at runtime

**2.** This code works perfectly well when tried within an Activity (without any fragments)

**3.** The ItemAdapter's getView() gets called only once

Comment: you can add your solution into the answer of your question so anyone who had that type of problem could find this solution in the web.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved, Hadn’t added android:fillViewport:”true” in the ScrollView**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    >


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

</ScrollView>


<!-- android:layout_gravity="left" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side. The drawer is
     given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->

<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="left"
          android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```